# Trouble Downloading

Tags: downloads

I have attempted 4 times to download Ubuntu ( I want to try before buying)

Each time, I avoid the payPal payment ( I don't have an account) I choose download for free. I am taken to a page that says " access denied"

I don't mind paying for it if I like it> is it free or not?

TS

Comment: It's free. And it should work. Just checked it, and no problems for me.

Comment: It is free - it is probably just that the browser or Internet Service Provider blocks it or something. You can get it directly from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) - the same downloads, just skips the donation bit.

Answer (score 3):

It's free. The paypal thing is donation and not payment. You're probably facing some sort of server error. If you continue to have problems with ubuntu.com directly, go [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors), and take your piece of Free Software:

[Ubuntu Mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)